# Add localization

Tags: ios, localization

Hi I have an app on the ios appstore https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/baby-tweets-english/id681812385?ls=1&mt=8

I delivered the current version with an additional localization  support for Swedish (i saved it and can see it on my itunes connect portal)

Howerver when i enter the Swedish app store, signed in with a Swedish credit card I still see the description in english. does the app store also look at the IP of where i enter the store from?  what can be the reason that the Swedish isn't displayed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The displayed description is based on your language preference in Settings.

You won't see the Swedish description if your preferred language is set to English.

Comment: I have set the language settings to Swedish and unfortunately did not change the display page to Swedish